# Dynamically load storyBoards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I'm working on a storyBoard loading system and I need to check for the presence of a specific storyBoard.

I made a function checking for it (given a specific StoryBoard name) :

```
(NSString *)ressourceNameForDevice:(NSString *)rootName extension:(NSString *)ext
{
    NSString *retString = rootName;
    NSString *iPadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-iPad", rootName];
    NSString *iPhoneWideString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-wide", rootName];

    if (IS_IPAD &&
        (nil != [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:iPadString ofType:ext]))
    {
        retString = iPadString;
    }

    if (IS_IPHONE_WIDE &&
        (nil != [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:iPhoneWideString ofType:ext]))
    {
        retString = iPhoneWideString;
    }

    return retString;
}
```

I'm calling this function with `@"storyboard"` as extension argument.

My probleme is that the function fails on `nil != [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:iPhoneWideString ofType:ext]`, even though the storyBoard **IS** present in my project and bundle, it doesn't get found. I guess I should give it another extension, I tried with `@"nib"` too but no more result.

Anyone knows how to check that ?

Comment: What about: `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"xxx" bundle:nil]`?

Comment: The method I wrote is called to fill the `@"xxx"` part of this function, cause for a _Hello.storyboard_ there's a _Hello-wide.storyboard_ and a _Hello-iPad.storyboard_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that once a storyBoard gets compiled the ressource extension isn't `.storyboard` but `.storyboardc`, same way that a `.xib` compiled file has the `.nib` extension.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have "xyz.storyboard" in your project to be loaded. Then write it as:

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"xyz"
                                                             bundle: nil];
```

It should do the needful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The fact is that I already use this method but my problem comes from the fact that I have `xyz.storyboard`, `xyz-wide.storyboard` and `xyz-iPad.storyboard`. The method I wrote checks for the device type and the actual presence of a `xyz.storyboard` if on iPhone, `xyz-wide.storyboard` if on iPhone 4inch or `xyz-iPad.storyboard` if on iPad. I just need to know how to verify the presence of a storyBoard before loading it.

Comment: if you try to load xyz-wide.storyboard by passing "xyz-wide" as argument and get nil, that means the story board is not present.

Comment: I get that but I want to check for it before trying to load it.